# How to pass EBS userid while calling EBS webservices from Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-ebs

I am calling an EBS Webservice "Assign Roles " from Oracle APEX. It is getting called successfully and assiging the role to the required user. But if I go and check "wf_user_role_assignments" table, the created_by field has the userid for the apex user not the EBS user. How can i do that?

I am passing the EBS_ user_id while calling the webservice from APEX.
I debugged the code which is called from the webservice.

It calls "UMX_REGISTRATION_PVT" package, which in turn calls "wf_local_synch.propagateUserRole ". But the parameters that are being passed doesn't include "created_by" field.

```
 wf_local_synch.propagateUserRole (
    p_user_name        => l_requested_for_user_name,
    p_role_name        => l_wf_role_name,
    p_start_date       => l_requested_start_date,
    p_expiration_date  => l_requested_end_date,
    p_raiseErrors      => true,
    p_assignmentReason => l_justification);
```

So, when this proc is actually called it takes NULL value as "created_by" parameter.

After that when this proc calls WF_Directory.CreateUserRole, it assigns

```
l_creatby := nvl(CreateUserRole.created_by,WFA_SEC.USER_ID);
```

which takes the value of APEX user.

I want EBS userid to be populated in the created by field in "wf_user_role_assignments" table ? How can I do that, since "wf_local_synch.propagateUserRole" doesn't include that parameter while calling I am not able to pass the right value. And since this is a standard oracle package, it is not recommended to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

The created_by field is a standard audit field (known as a who column) in EBS - it is a foreign key to FND_USER, and has to correspond to an EBS user.  The webservice runs as a central EBS user with additional privs, and the system is going to set the value for this column as the user that the code is running as, not the user the code is running for.

It would be inadvisable to do this, as you would be bypassing the intent of the audit column.  So, the better question is, why do you want to do this?  And can you get the information from another place instead?